# Pointer to member variable of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, pointer-to-member

What is a safe way to accessing member variables through a shared object in C++?

In the code below, I make a shared variable and then a pointer to a member variable of it. However, the use_count remains unchanged and when I reset the shared variable the original variable is reset but not the pointer to member.

In other words, I could introduce some bugs by using b. The object it is pointing to shouldn't exist anymore.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int y;
    A(int x)
    {
        y = x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto a = make_shared<A>(1);
    cout << "a count: " << a.use_count() << endl; //prints a count: 1
    auto b = a->y;
    cout << "a count: " << a.use_count() << endl; //still prints a count: 1

    a.reset();

    cout << "a value: " << a << endl; //prints a value: 0
    cout << "b value: " << b << endl; //prints b value: 1

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use a combination of shared_ptr<A> and pointer-to-member such as A::*y, depending on your use case

Comment: If you are trying to protect against concurrent access to the same member from different threads, you could protect the member with a `std::mutex`

Comment: You probably want to use shared_ptr's aliasing constructor: `std::shared_ptr<int>(a, &a->y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a safe way to accessing member variables through a shared object in C++?

You are already doing it. The code you showed is safe.

> In the code below, I make a shared variable and then a pointer to a member variable of it.

No, you don't. `A::y` is an `int`. In the `auto b = a->y;` statement, `auto` deduces to `int`, not to `int&` or `int*`. So, you are creating a new `int` whose value is a copy of `y`. There is no pointer to `y`.

If you wanted something like that, you would have needed to use one of these instead:

```
auto &b = a->y;
... 
cout << "b value: " << b << endl;
```

```
auto *b = &(a->y); // or just: auto b = ...
... 
cout << "b value: " << *b << endl;
```

> However, the use_count remains unchanged

Correct, because you are not assigning `a` to another instance of `shared_ptr<A>`. That is what `use_count` represents - the number of `shared_ptr` objects that are sharing the same object in memory.

> when I reset the shared variable the original variable is reset but not the pointer to member.

Of course, because `b` is independent of `a` and is not a pointer to anything related to `a`.

> In other words, I could introduce some bugs by using b.

No, because `b` is not linked to `a`, so resetting `a` has no effect on `b`.

Now, if you did manage to accomplish what you are asking for (making `b` be a pointer to `y`), it is your responsibility to make sure the `A` object that `y` was accessed from remains valid in memory until you are done using `b`, otherwise dereferencing `b` will be **undefined behavior**. The STL won't save you from doing something stupid behind its back, like accessing an `A` object's member via a raw pointer after the object has been destroyed.

Comment: This is a great answer. Yes, I had meant `auto b = &(a->y)`

Answer (score 6):

```
auto b = a->y;
```

This will *copy* the value of `y`, so it's not a pointer to `y`, it's only a copy.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I think what I really wanted was `auto b = &(a->y);` and then `*b` in the cout statement.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/reset/

"Additionally, a call to this function has the same side effects as if shared_ptr's destructor was called before its value changed (including the deletion of the managed object if this shared_ptr was unique)"
So you will print destroyed object, and this is UB.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto a = make_shared<A>(1);
auto b = std::shared_ptr<int>(a, &a->y);
```

b is a shared pointer to y that does what you want.

This is known as the "aliasing constructor" of shared ptr.  It is intended for exactly this purpose; having a shared pointer into part of a larger shared ptr.

You can use it for lots of insane and fancy things on top of it.  Be careful when using it, as you can get strange states like empty non-null shared ptrs, and non-empty null shared ptrs.  But if you use it "normally" like the above, it will work fine.

What you did

```
auto a = make_shared<A>(1);
auto b = a->y;
```

simply copies `y` into `b`, no pointers are involved.

Comment: Thanks. This will return use_count() of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The moral of the story is don't hand out references to objects that may die before the reference. Design with every object's life-span in mind. One solution may be to copy the `std::shared_ptr` to make sure the reference is always pointing at the object another solution might be to pass a `std::weak_ptr` when you don't need the object to still be valid but you need to know so you don't try to use it. Only pass out pointers and references when you **know** the object will outlive them.