# accessing a variable from a shared pointer in c++ gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a below snippet of c++ code which gives segfault. Could anyone explain why this gives segmentation fault?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A {};

class B {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& getListOfB();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> m_ListOfB;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& B::getListOfB()
{
    return m_ListOfB;
}

using BPtr = std::shared_ptr<B>;
using AVector = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>;
using APtr = std::shared_ptr<A>;

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
    AVector &aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB();

    APtr report1 = std::make_shared<A>();
    aVector.push_back(report1);
    sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
    aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB(); // <-- fault happened

    return 0;
}
```

And running it gave me this stack trace.

```
0x00000000004013ea in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0xc50a25d35ec168ca) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:337
337           if (__atomic_load_n(__both_counts, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE) == __unique_ref)
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.35-22.fc36.x86_64 libgcc-12.2.1-4.fc36.x86_64 libstdc++-12.2.1-4.fc36.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004013ea in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0xc50a25d35ec168ca) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:337
#1  0x00000000004015ef in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count (this=0x41bf08, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1071
#2  0x0000000000401536 in std::__shared_ptr<A, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr (this=0x41bf00, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1524
#3  0x0000000000401552 in std::shared_ptr<A>::~shared_ptr (this=0x41bf00, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/shared_ptr.h:175
#4  0x000000000040315d in std::_Destroy<std::shared_ptr<A> > (__pointer=0x41bf00) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_construct.h:151
#5  0x0000000000402c15 in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<A> > > > > (
    __first=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xc50a25d35ec168d2>, __last=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x39>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_construct.h:163
#6  0x0000000000402659 in std::_Destroy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<A> > > > > (
    __first=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xc50a25d35ec168d2>, __last=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x39>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_construct.h:196   
#7  0x0000000000402069 in std::_Destroy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<A>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<A> > > >, std::shared_ptr<A> > (
    __first=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xc50a25d35ec168d2>, __last=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x39>) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/alloc_traits.h:850
#8  0x000000000040196e in std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<A> > >::operator= (this=0x41bec0, __x=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0) at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/vector.tcc:244
#9  0x0000000000401281 in main () at snippet.cpp:29
```

Comment: `Vector &aVector` is a reference into the 1st  `sharedPtrB`.  This get reassigned here `sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();` , which destroys the 1st `sharedPtrB` as it's the only managing object.  Now `aVector` is a dangling reference. And `aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB();` tries to assign through a dangling reference.

Comment: You could use an aliasing constructor of a shared pointer, q.v.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236893/4641116

Comment: @RichardCritten how come assigning to dangling reference gives a crash? I'm not dereferencing.

Comment: The dereference of the dangling reference happens here: `aVector =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that an error occurred during the execution of the code. Specifically, it seems to be related to the assignment aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB(); in the main function.

The issue arises because aVector is a reference to sharedPtrB->getListOfB(), and when you reassign aVector to sharedPtrB->getListOfB(), the vector m_ListOfB inside B gets destroyed, causing the shared pointers to be released. Consequently, when the original vector is destroyed, it tries to release the shared pointers again, leading to a double deletion and resulting in undefined behavior.

To resolve this issue, you can either avoid reassigning aVector to a new vector or modify your code to handle the ownership of shared pointers properly.

Solution -1

```
std::shared_ptr<B> sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
AVector& aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB();

APtr report1 = std::make_shared<A>();
aVector.push_back(report1);
// Do not reassign aVector here

// Alternatively, if you need to assign a new vector,
// create a new shared pointer for B instead
sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
AVector& newVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB();
// Use the newVector as needed
```

Solution -2

```
std::shared_ptr<B> sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
AVector& aVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB();

APtr report1 = std::make_shared<A>();
aVector.push_back(report1);

sharedPtrB = std::make_shared<B>();
AVector newVector = sharedPtrB->getListOfB(); // Create a new vector, not a 
reference

// Use newVector as needed
```

Comment: I actually cannot avoid reassigning to aVector or the sharedPtrB as it is actually happening in a loop. I only came up with that snippet to make it the least  footprint of code that crashes.

Comment: And could you elaborate about the double deletion? is it like this? 1st deletion happens when I reassign sharedPtrB with make_shared. And the second deletion happens when I reassign the aVector reference?

Comment: @jaeyong You can't reassign or rebind a reference. Once the reference `aVector` is created it always refers to the same object. When the object is destroyed the reference dangles.

Comment: @jaeyong • It cannot be caught at compile time.  It has to be caught before that, at programming time.